# enabling of textbox when a value in a drop down box selected

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

when I selected a option in an drop down list,text box would be enabled.And value I entered in that textbox will stored in database with a value selected in drop down box also.

Comment: First we want to see some effort from you. What have you tried?

Comment: Post relevant parts of the code that you already have. Specifically the HTML for the drop down and the AJAX call code for saving the data etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is sample code for enable textbox on selectbox option select.

Please do required changes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showtextbox()
{
var x=document.getElementById("intext").
x.disabled=false;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
<select onChange="showtextbox()"">
    <option >one</option>
    <option>two</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="intext" name="intext" disabled='disabled'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Use your php code to connect and insert data in database.

Comment: Excuse me friend do not spoon feed the members, let them tell what they have tried from their part and then we can help them out to achieve the solution from what they have done. Coz that helps them in learning things. If you post like this, they don't even look on what has been tried and they simply copy paste it and get things done. Don't make them lazy gooses. Sorry If my words have hurt you.

Comment: @AmGates: Noted. You are right. Will take care of it in future.